# How can I get a prompt information and use it inside a function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, function

I'm trying to create a rock, paper and scissors game using JavaScript, in the game I need to get a user choice (rock, paper or scissors) and a random computer choice (rock, paper or scissors), compare these choices and show a winner. But I can't get the user choice to compare with the computer choice.

I create a function getUserChoice() with a prompt to get a user choice and use the choice inside the function playRound () but the program don't show the prompt on the scream.

How can I fix this? and if I fix this the app will work?

```
<script>
            
            function getUserChoice() {
                let userChoice = window.prompt('rock, paper or scissors?')
            }
           
                       
            function getComputerChoice() {
                let computerChoice = Math.random; 
                    if (computerChoice < 0.34){return 'rock';} 
                    else if (computerChoice <= 0.67){return 'paper';}
                    else {return 'scissors';}
                
            }
                            
            
            function playRound(userChoice , computerChoice) {

                const playerSelection = getUserChoice();
                const computerSelection = getComputerChoice();
                
                    if (playerSelection === 'rock' && computerSelection === 'scissors') {
                    console.log('You win! Rock beats Scissors')
                    }
                    else if (playerSelection === 'scissors' && computerSelection === 'paper') {
                        console.log('You win! Scissors beats Paper')
                    }
                    else if(playerSelection === 'paper' && computerSelection === 'rock') {
                        console.log('You win! Paper beats Rock')
                    }
                    
                    else if(playerSelection === 'scissors' && computerSelection === 'rock') {
                        console.log('You lose! Rock beats Scissors')
                    }
                    
                    else if(playerSelection === 'paper' && computerSelection === 'scissors') {
                        console.log('You lose! Scissors beats Paper')
                    }
                    
                    else if (playerSelection === 'rock' && computerSelection === 'paper') {
                        console.log('You lose! Paper beats Rock')
                    }
                    
                    else {
                        console.log('Tie')
                    }
                }               
    </script>
```

Comment: are you executing `playRound()` anywhere?

Comment: I'm not seeing a call to `playRound` anywhere here, so is it possible you haven't started your rock, papers, scissors game?

Comment: `getUserChoice` doesn't return anything.  Did you mean to return something from it?

Comment: there is plenty sample JS code about Rock/paper/scissor on SO, why didn't you have a analize look on them to learn how to do this by your self ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok there are 3 issues here.

first of all `getUserChoice` doesn't return anything.

secondly you haven't called `Math.random` in `getComputerChoice` but made a reference to that `Math.random` method.

and lastly you haven't called the `playRound()` function.

so if we fix these issues, your code should work just fine.

```js
            function getUserChoice() {
                return window.prompt('rock, paper or scissors?')
            }
           
                       
            function getComputerChoice() {
                let computerChoice = Math.random(); 
                    if (computerChoice < 0.34){return 'rock';} 
                    else if (computerChoice <= 0.67){return 'paper';}
                    else {return 'scissors';}
                
            }
                            
            
            function playRound(userChoice , computerChoice) {

                const playerSelection = getUserChoice();
                const computerSelection = getComputerChoice();
                
                    if (playerSelection === 'rock' && computerSelection === 'scissors') {
                    console.log('You win! Rock beats Scissors')
                    }
                    else if (playerSelection === 'scissors' && computerSelection === 'paper') {
                        console.log('You win! Scissors beats Paper')
                    }
                    else if(playerSelection === 'paper' && computerSelection === 'rock') {
                        console.log('You win! Paper beats Rock')
                    }
                    
                    else if(playerSelection === 'scissors' && computerSelection === 'rock') {
                        console.log('You lose! Rock beats Scissors')
                    }
                    
                    else if(playerSelection === 'paper' && computerSelection === 'scissors') {
                        console.log('You lose! Scissors beats Paper')
                    }
                    
                    else if (playerSelection === 'rock' && computerSelection === 'paper') {
                        console.log('You lose! Paper beats Rock')
                    }
                    
                    else {
                        console.log('Tie')
                    }
                }          
                
                playRound();
```